# MongoDB: index on collection names themselves

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Say I have a simple user schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   username: String,
   password: String,

   notifications: [{

      message: String,
      dateCreated: Date,

   }]

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

but what if we have a lot of users and we break apart the model, making notifications it's own collection like so:

```
   var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

       username: String,
       password: String,


    });


    var notifsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

       message: String,
       dateCreated: Date,

    });

    module.exports = function getModel(userId){

          return mongoose.model('notifs_' + userId, notifsSchema)

    }
```

so my question is: if we make notifications collections by user, so we have 200 users, therefore 200 notifications collections - is MongoDB smart enough to be able to index by collection name somehow? So if we have 100,000 users MongoDB can fins the notifications collection called 'notifs_394939329443'?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add `userId` to your `notifsSchema` and then index that? Creating a collection per user makes things really messy.

Comment: I agree - it looks like MongoDB has a default cap on collection namespaces of 24,000...so only that many collections are permitted by default. So we hope to have far more users than that so that won't really work.